# How Do I Exit While Loop From Within a Switch Statement

Tags: powershell, scripting

In PowerShell, how do I exit this `while` loop that is nested inside a `switch` statement, without executing the code immediately following the `while` block?  I can't seem to figure it out.  Everything I've tried so far results in that block of code being executed.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Check for the presence of a file and notify user if file is
   detected.
2. Check again every 10 seconds and notify user
3. If the file is not detected, then exit the loop and switch, and continue
   with Step #2
4. If the file is still detected after 30 seconds, timeout and exit
   the script entirely.

Here's the code:

```
try {
    #Step 1
    $Prompt = <Some Notification Dialog with two buttons>
    switch ($Prompt){
        'YES' {
            # Display the Windows Control Panel

            #Wait for user to manually uninstall an application - which removes a file from the path we will check later.
            $Timeout = New-Timespan -Seconds 30
            $Stopwatch = [Dispatch.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

            while ($Stopwatch.elapsed -lt $Timeout) {
                if (Test-Path -Path "C:\SomeFile.exe" -PathType Leaf) {
                    Write-Host "The file is still there, remove it!"
                    return
                }
                Start-Sleep 10
            }

            #After timeout is reached, notify user and exit the script
            Write-Host "Timeout reached, exiting script"
            Exit-Script -ExitCode $mainExitCode #Variable is declared earlier in the script
        }
        'NO' {
            # Do something and exit script
        }
    }

    # Step 2
    # Code that does something here

    # Step 3
    # Code that does something here
} catch {
    # Error Handling Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use break with a label, to exit a specific loop (a switch statements counts as a loop), see [about_break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break).

```
$a = 0
$test = 1
:test switch ($test) {
    1 {
        Write-Output 'Start'
        while ($a -lt 100)
        {
            Write-Output $a
            $a++
            if ($a -eq 5) {
                break test
            }
        }
        Write-Output 'End'
    }
}
Write-Output "EoS"
```

Comment: Didn't know much about using labels with the break command, but now I do, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you see without the try/catch?  I get an exception:  `Unable to find type [Dispatch.Stopwatch]`.  Otherwise the return works ok for me.

I think what you want is break with a label going outside the switch?  Then steps 2 & 3 will run.  I altered the code to make a manageable example.  This is more ideal when asking a question.  I don't know what exit-script is.

```
echo hi > file

#try {
    #Step 1
    $Prompt = '<Some Notification Dialog with two buttons>'
    $Prompt = 'yes'
:atswitch    switch ($Prompt){
        'YES' {
            'Display the Windows Control Panel'

            #Wait for user to manually uninstall an application - which removes a file from the path we will check later.
            $Timeout = New-Timespan -Seconds 30
            #$Stopwatch = [Dispatch.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

            while (1) {
                if (Test-Path -Path "file" -PathType Leaf) {
                    Write-Host "The file is still there, remove it!"
                    break atswitch
                }
                Start-Sleep 10
            }

            #After timeout is reached, notify user and exit the script
            Write-Host "Timeout reached, exiting script"
            'Exit-Script -ExitCode $mainExitCode #Variable is declared earlier in the script'
        }
        'NO' {
            'Do something and exit script'
        }
    }

    # Step 2
    'Code that does something here'

    # Step 3
    'Code that does something here2'
#} catch {
#    'Error Handling Code Here'
#}
```

Comment: No, I don't get any errors.  The Try/Catch block works for me and the Stopwatch does start counting down when I debug the code, so I know all is working.  It's just my logic to avoid exiting being run all the time that's my problem right now.

Comment: break :atswitch

Comment: Thanks, adding the label worked for me.  Much appreciated.